# How can I add a trigger of workflow to indicate the state of a deployed workflow in nodered?

Tags: node-red

I use nodered a visualization of my computation workflow and I have a computation engine to support it. I want to have a sign in nodered to show how is the computation going, such as executing, failed or succeeded.
In the default html, there is a indicator. But I do not know how to change it to a trigger. The indicator is in the circle of following pic.

[image]

I wonder whether I can make it a trigger by adding a js function to poll my computing engine and show state accordingly, or I can implement the idea in some other ways.

Answer (score 0):

The Node-RED flow editor is not meant to be a dashboard, it is there to edit the flow, not give real time feedback of things happening on the backend.

The field you have highlighted is a property of the node, this can not be changed at runtime, only by editing the node and deploying.

The only state information a node in the flow can show is to use the `node.status()` function as described in the docs [here](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/status)